Off the top of your head, or heads?
When addressing a group of people, should the idiom 'off the top of one's head' be used with singular or plural forms?
As in,

Off the top/s of your head/s, is Kolkata more populous than Hyderabad?


There's a lot of similar (but not identical) questions: shake your head, blow your head off, everybody's head, body's immune system. Although the problem is to work which applies here.

@StuartF thank you; I particularly like the latter two references for their relevance here; However, I still find the implied problem non-trivial, as use of both plural forms in the idiom seems unintuitive to me. How would you answer the question, then?

In the OP's context here, it's really just a matter of whether the speaker thinks he's addressing multiple people individually, or as a group. Thus "If you agree with me, nod your head[s]" is fine with either plurality, depending on who exactly the speaker thinks you refers to.

The thread Do you pluralize the singular possessions of items or people associated with individual members of a plural group? is also relevant. But in most individual cases, the choice between distributive singular and distributive plural needs careful thought. Here, the plural sounds better to me, to sound inclusive. But I'd perversely use 'top of your heads'. 'From the bottom of your hearts' certainly sounds better.

Using the plural make it unambiguous, since people don't have two heads (though they might have two phones). It makes it clear that everybody is being asked, not a specific person. Though perhaps it should be "off the tops of your heads".
